# Spring session - customize session content

Tags: java, spring, spring-session

I'm using Spring-boot, spring-security and spring-session + redis.
My web application stores a lot of information in HTTP Session, for example Controllers because it is JSF and I use ViewScope.

Do you have any ideas how to limit the classes that should be stored in redis? Or limit session attributes? Is there any option to choose which HTTP session data should be stored by spring-session in redis?

For example, I would like to store in redis only authentication-related data (Spring Security), but omit my old Controllers (controllers still
need to be stored in HTTP session).

Comment: It is generally not a good idea to store too much data in your session, certainly not whole controllers. That being said, i have seen solutions where the session handling is left to Spring and certain elements, e.g. auth data, are sent to Redis by using Spring's RedisTemplate.

Comment: @Pao do you have any example? Where did you see it? I searched for just such a solution on github, but did not find it.

Comment: It was not my code, so i can't share it, and i don't remember it exactly, but i think in essence the default Spring session was used and additionally a simple Spring component with a RedisTemplate<K, V> talked with Redis, mainly sending the data that was required for sessions of other applications. The downside is that you have do the communication with Redis on your own. IIRC the goal was to not share the whole session, like in your case, but limit it to the required data.